# String on a .txt file to bitmap

Tags: java, android, string, image, bitmapfactory

i have a question on my exersise.
my question is
i have in my memory card a .txt file with a string inside that.
i want to make an image using that string.
the image that i want to create i dont care if i just an image with no understandable content, i just want to make that string as an image on an imageview.

i try many thinks but i cant do anything

i try to read tha string as a byte [] array, and then to use the Bitmapfactory(), but is send me a null image on the image view.

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `BitmapFactory` expects **compressed image data**. It has no idea how to interpret the values you are giving it. What you can do as an alternative is go over the `byte[]` yourself, convert it into an `int[]` and use [Bitmap.setPixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: could you please give me more details with your idea?

Comment: Read the api doc - it's pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
private Bitmap getViewBitmap ( String textString ) {
    View view = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    TextView txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
    txt.setText(textString);

    int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(187, 187);
    view.measure(spec,spec);
    view.layout(0, 0, 187, 187);

    Bitmap cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cache);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return cache;
}
```

Comment: those are width and height. You can also use LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: with this code i must take a random bitmap created from the string?